# Issue publishing a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am trying to publish a Chrome Extension to the Chrome Web Store and it seems like Google Rejected it while reviewing. The message which they gave me is -

```
Your item did not comply with the following section of our Programme policies:


'User Data Privacy'

Your product violates the 'Use of Permissions' section of the policy, which requires that you:

Request access to the narrowest permissions necessary to implement your product’s features or services.
If more than one permission could be used to implement a feature, you must request those with the least access to data or functionality.
Don't attempt to 'future proof' your product by requesting a permission that might benefit services or features that have not yet been implemented.
```

In my Manifest file - I have `"permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],`

And in my description, I have added - `This extension will fetch the key's - Tenant ID and your Token from your browser's stored local storage when the page is loaded and display and copy it.`

Not sure, why it is being rejected. I am not sure if this question would be an appropriate one to ask here but just thought of giving it a try if anyone has any idea about what I need to change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: This is a problem of the review process in the web store being vague and anti-human, not a programming problem so this is off-topic here. Try asking on a Google's product forum like [this one](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions), preferably attach your extension or post a link to the source repository.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the information. I wasn't sure if this is the right channel to ask this question hence I stated that above but just wanted to see if anyone has any idea. Sorry for that.

Comment: We are facing the same issue with our plugin. Did your issue above get resolved? Pl advice. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I mean it is probably because you said it requires "local storage" and probably other "ify" permissions that google said in their 'User Data Privacy.' They said in that paragraph that you must try to minimize the number of permissions your extension requires. Try to rephrase it and see if that helps.  Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. Because I have those 3 permissions, I also have to specify the Permission Justification and I have added this verbiage as in the next comment -

Comment: **activeTab** - 

The activeTab permission is needed because this extension will fetch the value for the key stored in the currently active tab when the user invokes the extension in order to be able to interact with a page after the user clicks on extension.

**declarativeContent** - 

The Declarative Content API requires this permission because it needs to take the the Get LocatStoarge page action depending on the current page the user is on.

**storage** - 

Require this permission because the API needs to retrieve the data stored in the 
memory

Is there any issue with this?

Comment: I don't really see any flaws in this so my guess is that google doesn't like the permissions that you are asking for. See if any extensions function like yours and see permissions required by them.  Good Luck!

Comment: This is a problem of the review process in the web store being vague and anti-human, not a programming problem so this is off-topic here because it attracts answers like this one that are pure guesses not based on anything related to development.